# how can i recover my deleted documents mongodb 3.6 single node?

Tags: mongodb

We tried to run mongod --repair but instead of recovering the files it deleted them.

Is there a way to recover these data? maybe partially?

We are using standalone mongodb.

Thanks

Comment: using mongodb 3.6 and standalone deleted documents need recover

Comment: How did you delete it? Did you do a `drop()` operation, `deleteMany()`, or similar?